# Conceptualising sound FX for a short film that has a gaming vibe.

Tags: game, shortfilm, sound-fx

I am currently working on post production of a short film. The film has the whole gaming vibe going on. My idea is to be able to merge also the VFX with the sound design. I looked for some retro game sounds, such as the ones in Zelda, Mario and other games mostly from the 80's and 90's. 
I also looked at games like Scott Pilgrim Vs The World: The Game that have the retro games spirit. I wonder if I can get recommendations on where to get some free material either to use it or to give me some sort of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I remember, years ago, finding a little freeware program that generates 8 bit synth FX, but i can't remember what it was called. [Here](http://www.bfxr.net/) is a tool i found that does something similar.

There seem to be quite a few options if you google something like "free 8 bit fx generator". Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Bitcrushing ('8 bit'), distortion, bleeps and filtered synths, sparkly sounds for the 80s...for the 90s more sweeping sounds and low booming stuff, echoes and reverb...

freesound.org is a favorite resource.